# How to push data in document db using webjobs?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I have written following code to read the data from text file and then separate the sentences and send them to azure event hub.

I am able to send the data to event hub but not able to push data in document db.

How to push data in document db using webjobs? I am running webjobs from console application, Do I need add more configuration to run it locally?
 Program.cs

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Error;

            var eventHubConfig = new EventHubConfiguration();
            eventHubConfig.AddReceiver(eventHubName, connectionString);
            config.UseEventHub(eventHubConfig);

            JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
            config.DashboardConnectionString = StorageConnectionString;
            if (config.IsDevelopment)
            {
                config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
            }

            //Send test messages
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                SendMessagesToEventHub();
            });

            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
```

function.cs

```
class Functions
    {
        public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("azurepochub")] EventData message, [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DocumentDB("testcosmosdb01122018", "Items", ConnectionStringSetting = "dbConnctionString")]out dynamic document)
        {
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes());

            document = data;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine($"Message received. Data: '{data}'");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I have written following code..."   and where is it?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get answer from github [Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions). If we want to insert document to the Azure documentdb, we need to insert the object into it. In your case, your output is string.

> Do I need add more configuration to run it locally?

I also do demo for that. The following is the detail steps

1.Create an .net framework Webjob project.

2.Add the AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString in the App.config file.

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- Service Bus specific app setings for messaging connections -->
    <add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="Endpoint=sb://[your namespace].servicebus.windows.net;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=[your secret]" />
    <add key ="AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString" value="xxxxx"/>
 </appSettings>
```

[image]

3.Add the following code in the Program.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

namespace WebJobTest
{
    // To learn more about Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320976
    class Program
    {
        // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
        // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
        private static string eventHubName = "eventhubNam";
        private static string connectionString = "eventhub connectionstring";
        static void Main()
        {
            JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Error;

            var eventHubConfig = new EventHubConfiguration();
            eventHubConfig.AddReceiver(eventHubName, connectionString);
            config.UseDocumentDB(new DocumentDBConfiguration
            {
                ConnectionString = "DocumentDB ConnectionString"
            });
            config.UseEventHub(eventHubConfig);
            config.DashboardConnectionString = "storage connection string";
            JobHost host = new JobHost(config);

            if (config.IsDevelopment)
            {
                config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
            }

            //Send test messages
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                SendMessagesToEventHub();
            });

            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
        static void SendMessagesToEventHub()
        {
            var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, eventHubName);
              try
                {
                    var message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, message);
                    eventHubClient.Send(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} > Exception: {1}", DateTime.Now, exception.Message);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }

                Thread.Sleep(200);

        }
    }
}
```

4.In the function.cs

```
 public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("eventhub name")] EventData message, [DocumentDB("document Database name", "collection", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString")]out Item document)
    {
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes());

        document = new Item{Text = data};
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine($"Message received. Data: '{data}'");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Text;

    }
```

5.Check the result from console.

[image]

6. **Finish** debug from the console then check from the Azure documentdb

[image]